# Calculate the width of a grouped tableview cell

Tags: uitableview, uilabel

I'm trying to place two `UILabel` on the same vertical axis within a `UITableViewCell`, and have them take up 50% of the cell's width, when the cell is a **grouped** table cell.

I've tried `self.frame.size.width / 2`, but the width that `self.frame.size.width` looks like the width of the entire cell as if it were not a grouped cell. In other words, it seems to be the width of the whole screen, in a full screen table.

I also compared `self.frame.size.width` to `self.contentView.frame.size.width` and both appear to be the same, and are not the actual width of the grouped cell, I don't believe.

When I initialize the `UILabel` with a specified frame, and specify the **x-axis** to as `0`, the label does place itself on the left edge of the grouped cell, which is great! That's what I want.

But, for the 2nd `UILabel` that I wish to be to the right of the 1st label, on the same horizontal axis, I do not know how to calculate where to start for the label's frame's x-axis.

Likewise, I do not know how to calculate width for either of these labels, because I can't seem to get the width of the grouped cell.

I feel like there must be a way to get the exact width, because for the first label, giving the label's frame an x-axis of 0 puts it right on the edge of the cell, which is exactly as i need. So I need like internally, this code know the width of that cell too, somewhere.

Comment: For your issue of placing `label2` right next to `label1`, put `label1.frame.size.width` in place of the __x-axis__ of `label2`'s frame.

Comment: But, how would I make label1 half the width of the cell?

Comment: Check if `cell.contentView.frame.size.width` works. Also add the label to `cell.contentView` and not just the `cell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a good way to achieve this. If you're subclassing `UITableViewCell` and want to adjust the cell's sub-views, then you need to perform these calculations and frame adjustments inside of the `layoutSubviews:` method. Inside of this method, the cell's `contentView` will be the intended width, even when using a grouped cell. Below is what my `layoutSubviews` function looks like ...

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    // half of the cell's content view width
    CGFloat halfCellWidth = self.contentView.frame.size.width / 2;

    // the dimensions of the message label, primarily for the height
    CGSize mesageLabelDimensions = [_message.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]
                                             constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width - (LEFT_RIGHT_MARGIN * 2), 500.0)];

    // adjust the frames of the cell labels
    _source.frame = CGRectMake(LEFT_RIGHT_MARGIN, TOP_BOTTOM_MARGIN, halfCellWidth - LEFT_RIGHT_MARGIN, LABEL_LINE_HEIGHT);
    _timestamp.frame = CGRectMake(halfCellWidth, TOP_BOTTOM_MARGIN, halfCellWidth - LEFT_RIGHT_MARGIN, LABEL_LINE_HEIGHT);
    _message.frame = CGRectMake(LEFT_RIGHT_MARGIN, LABEL_LINE_HEIGHT + (TOP_BOTTOM_MARGIN * 2), mesageLabelDimensions.width, mesageLabelDimensions.height);

}
```